Is there a way to add a taxonomy (not a term) ACF field
I want to add a field where users can pick a taxonomy. I know there's a 'Taxonomy' field type, but what that actually provides a list of taxonomy terms, and I want them to be able to pick the actual taxonomy itself, not one of it's terms.
Is there any way to do this with ACF?

You can create a dropdown field, and then use a filter to populate it's options.

Need to dynamically populate a field’s choices? This tutorial shows how to take a value saved to an options page and use it to override the choices array for a Select field.
The ‘choices’ array attribute is also used with the Radio Button and Checkbox fields. Most of this tutorial applies to any of these fields, but the AJAX example can only be used with the Select field.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/
